# If done everyday, it's civilized. If only done when something's wrong, it's nasty

Tags: riddle, word

> When speaking of doing this **everyday as a daily routine**, this is a **civilized** thing to do.
>
> When speaking of doing this **only when something's wrong**, this is a **nasty** thing to do.

What is this thing we all do?

<sub>*Note: No censoring is required for this action in both cases.*</sub>

Comment: cenlvat pbzrf gb zvaq, ohg V pna'g znxr "anfgl" dhvgr svg

Comment: V jnf guvaxvat "ehaavat", ohg vg qbrfa'g ernyyl svg jvgu pvivyvmrq

Comment: My guess would be "pyrnavat gur gbvyrg".

Comment: @WhatsUp That's... not part of a daily routine ^^"

Comment: @SteveV Of course it's not the answer.

Comment: @Pepper Not the answer.

Comment: I think @WhatsUp is onto something, turer ner frireny bgure ultvravp npgvivgvrf gung zngpu dhvgr jryy

Comment: N ovg qnex, ohg pyrnavat n xavsr?

Comment: @user That's... not part of a daily routine ^^"

Comment: @riskymysteries Really? Ng bhe ubhfr, jr qb vg rirel qnl. Qba'g lbh phg irtrgnoyrf naq fghss?

Comment: @user It's big a stretch to say *everybody* uses one everyday.

Comment: I would guess: Yrnivat? Orpnhfr zbfg crbcyr yrnir sbe jbex be fpubby, ohg yrnivat jura fbzrguvat'f jebat pna or pbafvqrerq ehqr/anfgl Similar to @Pepper's comment

Comment: My new guess after @WhatsUp 's comment is jnfuvat lbhe unaqf: pvivyvfrq (rfcrpvnyyl qhevat n cnaqrzvp), naq jnfuvat lbhe unaqf bs fbzrguvat jebat/onq vf abg avpr!

Comment: @Pepper This is my guess too. Why didn't you propose this as an answer? It seems weird to me that such a question has only one answer 20h later, and that everybody is guessing in comments. I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: @xhienne You're right, I should have, but I don't mind either way :) I'll post another one that I think fits relatively well!

Comment: @YonatanN Censored in both cases.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the answer is

> washing one's hand

When speaking of doing this everyday as a daily routine, this is a civilized thing to do.

> Washing one's hand is considered basic hygiene

When speaking of doing this only when something's wrong, this is a nasty thing to do.

> This alludes to the idiomatic "washing one's hands of something" which means (quoting [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wash_one%27s_hands_of)): To absolve oneself of responsibility or future blame for; to refuse to have any further involvement with

Answer (score 6):

Here is another possible answer

> **wearing a mask** : civilized during the pandemic | when something's wrong = during a heist/theft/etc

Comment: During a rot13(urvfg/gursg/rgp), it's really unusual for it to be called nasty to rot13(jrne n znfx), as it's the rot13(urvfg/gursg/rgp) that is bad.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of different answers which kind of fit but I think the answer is

> Brushing your teeth

When speaking of doing this everyday as a daily routine, this is a civilized thing to do.

> Brushing one's teeth (preferably 2-3 times a day) is part of a healthy daily routine

When speaking of doing this only when something's wrong, this is a nasty thing to do.

> If something is *wrong* with your teeth, then it usually requires intervention by a dentist. This is both nasty with respect to the pain caused and also from a hygienic perspective.

Comment: It's probably nasty to have rot13(onq grrgu), but rot13(oehfuvat) is nonetheless the *same* concept in both cases in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another fit:

> launder

When speaking of doing this everyday as a daily routine, this is a civilized thing to do:

> Wash and iron (clothes or linen).
>  "He wasn't used to laundering his own bed linen."
>  (source: Google/Oxford Languages)

When speaking of doing this only when something's wrong, this is a nasty thing to do:

> Conceal the origins of (money obtained illegally), typically by transfers involving foreign banks or legitimate businesses.
>  "$123,000 had been laundered through Geneva bank accounts."
>  Alter (information) to make it appear more acceptable.
>  "We began to notice attempts to launder the data retrospectively."
>  (source: Google/Oxford Languages)

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: I didn't, but I don't find it common to rot13(qb ynhaqel) as a daily routine.

Answer (score -1):

My answer is:

> Laugh

Because:

> It's healthy to laugh every day but to laugh when something is wrong is schadenfreude.